# how to get combine from Two select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

my table is,

```
ID   First_Name    Last_name    manager_ID     Unique_ID
12    Jon           Doe          25             CN=Jon Doe, DC=test,DC=COM
25    Steve         Smith        39             CN=steve smith, DC=test,dc=com
```

I want to write a sql that will give me manager's unique ID,

```
select manager_id from test where ID = '12'
```

this will give me users manager_ID

```
select unique_id from test where ID = '25'
```

can i combine above sql in one statement that will give me user's manager's unique_id as output?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a self-join:

```
select m.unique_id
from test t join
     test m
     on t.manager_id = m.id
where t.ID = 12;
```

Note that I remove the single quotes around `12`.  Presumably, `id` is an integer.  You should not be comparing an integer to a string.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of joining it to the same table, you can also make a nested subquery statement like this.

```
SELECT unique_id FROM test WHERE ID =(SELECT manager_id FROM test WHERE ID = 12);
```

The inner query outputs the `manager_id` where `id` of `person` equals 12 and the outer query gives the `unique_id` of the related manager.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @hellow is it ok now

Comment: More like that, but yeah, looks definityly better.